# WML: A <do> element does not have a type defined

Tags: wml

I am trying to run this WML example on variables which I found in my WML textbook but it is giving me an error every time on the same line/statement. This is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.3//EN" 
 "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml13.dtd"> 
<wml> 
<card id="card1" title="First Card" newcontext="true">
    <p>
        Card 1... <br/>
        card1 var1=$(card1_var1) <br/>
        card2 var1=$(card2_var1) <br/>
        card3 var1=$(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="accept" label="Next Card">
            <go href="#card2">
                <setvar name="card1_var1" value="val_1"/>
            </go>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
<card id="card2" title="Second Card">
    <p>
        Card2 ...<br/>
        Card1 var1 = $(card1_var1) <br/>
        Card2 var1 = $(card2_var1) <br/>
        Card3 var1 = $(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="accept" label="First Card">
            <go href="#card1"/>
        </do>
        <do type="accept" label="Third Card">
            <go href="#card3">
                <setvar name="card2_var1" value="val_2"/>
            </go>
        </do>
        <do type="prev" label="Previous Card">
            <prev/>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
<card id="card3" title="Third Card">
    <onevent type="onenterforward">
        <refresh>
            <setvar name="card3_var1 " value="val_3"/>
        </refresh>
    </onevent>
    <p>
        Card 3 ...<br/>
        Card1 var1 = $(card1_var1) <br/>
        Card2 var1 = $(card2_var1) <br/>
        Card3 var1 = $(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="prev" label="Previous">
            <prev/>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
```

I am getting error at line 26. Even thought the type is defined over there, it still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted has a few errors that cause it to fail validation. These could just be cut-and-paste issues when posting to StackOverflow, or real errors that might have caused a parser to fail.

Line 1: The XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0"?>` should be in the first column; in your example it is indented.

Line 53: The closing WML tag `</wml>` is missing.

---

There are also two minor fixes that may be helpful:

Line 1: Add an encoding to the XML declaration e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Line 40: There is an errant space character in `name="card3_var1 "` so the variable does not get updated correctly

---

With those corrections in place your WML validates according to the W3C Validator, so it should be fine. I tried it in an Openwave 6.2.2 SDK and it seems to work without any errors.

Corrected example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.3//EN" 
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml13.dtd"> 
<wml> 
<card id="card1" title="First Card" newcontext="true">
    <p>
        Card 1... <br/>
        card1 var1=$(card1_var1) <br/>
        card2 var1=$(card2_var1) <br/>
        card3 var1=$(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="accept" label="Next Card">
            <go href="#card2">
                <setvar name="card1_var1" value="val_1"/>
            </go>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
<card id="card2" title="Second Card">
    <p>
        Card2 ...<br/>
        Card1 var1 = $(card1_var1) <br/>
        Card2 var1 = $(card2_var1) <br/>
        Card3 var1 = $(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="accept" label="First Card">
            <go href="#card1"/>
        </do>
        <do type="accept" label="Third Card">
            <go href="#card3">
                <setvar name="card2_var1" value="val_2"/>
            </go>
        </do>
        <do type="prev" label="Previous Card">
            <prev/>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
<card id="card3" title="Third Card">
    <onevent type="onenterforward">
        <refresh>
            <setvar name="card3_var1" value="val_3"/>
        </refresh>
    </onevent>
    <p>
        Card 3 ...<br/>
        Card1 var1 = $(card1_var1) <br/>
        Card2 var1 = $(card2_var1) <br/>
        Card3 var1 = $(card3_var1) <br/>
        <do type="prev" label="Previous">
            <prev/>
        </do>
    </p>
</card>
</wml>
```